# defuse php - Your system does not have a secure random number generator

Tags: php

I just fetched the defuse-crypto.phar file and put it into my project
I used

```
require_once "defuse-crypto.phar"
```

added

```
use Defuse\Crypto\Key;
use Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
```

and tried to use it but gets

> "Your system does not have a secure random number generator."

I got a little bewildered as it says it only requires PHP 5.4, but random_bytes is PHP 7+
Then I noticed the paragonie library inside the phar file.
Do I need to do anything to activate that? Because I obviously need a polyfill
or is there something else I need on the server?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to do anything to "activate" the polyfill - it is already loaded as soon as you `use` anything within the `Defuse` namespace.
You can verify this by calling `get_included_files()` after you do that:

```
<?php
require_once 'path/to/defuse-crypto.phar';
use Defuse\Crypto;
var_dump(\get_included_files());
```

And in the dumped array output, you should see an element containing this:

```
phar://path/to/defuse-crypto.phar/vendor/paragonie/random_compat/lib/random.php
```

---

The error message you're getting, unfortunately, means exactly what it says - you don't have a secure PRNG on your system (or PHP cannot access it).

If you're running Linux, make sure that PHP can access `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: Thank you for your insight
adding /dev/urandom to open_basedir helped !